# Add yrs to Date calculated column not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have a date column e.g 14/02/2023
I tried using the formula below

```
=DATE(YEAR(DatePicture+5),MONTH(DatePicture),DAY(DatePicture))
```

DatePicture is the name of the date column. It has been set to **Date Only** and Display Format **Standard**

But the date is not changing at all.it should be returning14/02/2028
Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(DatePicture)+5,MONTH(DatePicture),DAY(DatePicture))
```

It's `YEAR(DateColumn)+5` and not `YEAR(DateColumn+5)`.

In my test, `[DateReported]` is a date column:
[image: formula]
[image: plus 5 years]

Comment: Thanks jleture not sure how i missed  that. Good point out